# Using many dynamic Google Maps on modals on the same page - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a shops page with 12 stores. Each store has a button to show it's individual position on the map. The problem is it's not working **(I get the same position on every map, it's supposed to be dynamic)**.

**What I'm doing is loading a map inside the ruby block for each shop (Map is loading 12 times - 12 requests to the Google API):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBktelhtX7My2gbXhZIR8J9Lu6XXXQ1nNM">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var LocationData = [
        [<%= shop.latitude %>, <%= shop.longitude %>, '<%= shop.direction %>']
    ];
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-<%= shop.id %>'),
            mapOptions);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        for (var i in LocationData) {
            var p = LocationData[i];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
            bounds.extend(latlng);
            var image = 'assets/marcador_sushi.png';

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                icon: image,
                map: map,
                title: p[2]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(this.title);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm thinking you are overriding the global initialize() function 12 times.  So, when the window load event is fired, only the last definition of initialize is executed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how should I deal with this in order to have 12 independent maps without overriding functions?

Comment: See my answer below for a rough example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global function (perhaps in `app/assets/application.js`) that might look something like this:

```
  function addShopMap(shop_id, lat, lng, direction){
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-'+shop_id),
        mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    var image = 'assets/marcador_sushi.png';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: image,
        map: map,
        title: direction
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.title);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
```

Then you should call this function in each erb block for a shop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  addShopMap('<%= shop.id %>', <%= shop.latitude %>, <%= shop.longitude %>, '<%= shop.direction %>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, should the block have also the div inside?

Comment: <section class="col-12 mapa">
              <div id="map-canvas-<%= shop.id %>" class="block googlemap" style="display: block;height: 300px;">
           </section>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         addShopMap('<%= shop.id %>', <%= shop.latitude %>, <%= shop.longitude %>, '<%= shop.direction %>');
       </script>